# good textbooks which deal with convex geometry, especially convex polyhedral cones and convex polytopes

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry

I study toric varieties. In toric geometry, we use convex geometry, especially convex polyhedral cones and convex polytopes. Are there good textbooks which deal with convex geometry, especially convex polyhedral cones and convex polytopes.

Comment: "Lectures on Polytopes" by Ziegler is a standard reference.

Comment: Chapters 1--5 of Lauritzen's *Undergraduate convexity* (2013) and Chapters 1--12 of Schrijver's *Theory of Linear and Integer Programming* should cover the basics rigorously, I believe. There is also [a work-in-progress text by Antoine Chambert-Loir on tropical geometry](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~antoine.chambert-loir/enseignement/2020-21/gt/toptrop.pdf), written in Bourbaki style, although it will likely go through more revisions.

Comment: If you're also interested in unpublished notes, I recommend Gaku Liu's notes on "Polyhedral Combinatorics": https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TRg7iQ0RpIRteF2IUiKIe3E-YagVnkH0/view

Comment: Self promotion: Chapter 5 of "How many zeroes?" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05346) develops (from scratch) all convex geometry needed for basics of toric varieties, in particular for a toric proof of Bernstein-Kushnirenko theorem (and a bit more).

Comment: G. Ewald: Combinatorial Convexity and Algebraic Geometry, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer, 1996